Hot Reloading Scala.js
How to hot reload in scala.js application while in development
I am manually reloading the Scala.js application during development. However, I need the ability to reload and immediately reflect the changes made, similar to the way React hot reload works.

Please google any answers and try them out. If it didn't work kindly mention what have you tried so far and the community will help you out.

Relevant Scala.js issue: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/4643

My understanding, is that "Hot reload" can have a very specific meaning in which the state of the program is preserved by replacing a module at runtime, thus altering program behaviour without alter state. I do not believe this "true hot reloading" to be (at least easily) possible in scalaJS.
If want "fast refresh on change" - i.e. page reload (but fast, cca 50ms) you could try pasting this into a console (should be < 5 seconds to get going if you already have scala-cli and coursier) and following the breadcrumbs;
scala-cli --version && \
cs version && \
git clone https://github.com/Quafadas/viteless.git && \
cd viteless && \
cs launch io.github.quafadas:live-server-scala-cli-js_3:0.1.4

Full disclosure, that's my own "homebrewed" solution.
The wider scalajs community uses vite - there are many templates available. You could try this as a starting point, for example;
https://github.com/keynmol/scalajs-scala-cli-vite-template
